# Custom control bar at top of window

Tags: cocoa, user-interface

I want to create a control bar, if that's what it's called, with icons like those shown on the right side of the screen shot.  This is a screenshot from Sparrow, and as you can see there are icons (buttons) on the top right of the 'control bar'.

[image]

I've seen this in Sparrow, Coda, Reeder, and Ecoute, but I've had trouble researching it because I don't know what the actual name for that bar is, and I'm new to Cocoa.

How do I create this type of UI?

Comment: I assume you mean the icons on the right. The ones on the left are the standard window controls; they come with every window you create. What app is this screenshot from?

Comment: Yes, I mean the buttons on the right of the control bar.  That is a screenshot from Sparrow, though I have seen the technique in many apps.  Coda uses it heavily, and it is used nicely in Reeder and Ecoute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of those apps are made with the `INAppStoreWindow` class.

Check it out on Github:
https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow

Give credit to the great developer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The bar is called the Title Bar.  Also, here is nice [tutorial](http://www.behindtechlines.com/2012/05/25/cocoa-add-a-search-bar-and-other-controls-to-titlebar/) of what I wanted.